# How do I use a foreach loop in Java to loop through the values in a HashMap?

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
private String dataToString(){
    Map data = (HashMap<MyClass.Key, String>) getData();
    String toString = "";
    for( MyClass.Key key: data.keySet() ){
        toString += key.toString() + ": " + data.get( key );
    return toString;
}
```

I get an error in the for line that says:

```
incompatible types
found : java.lang.Object
required: MyClass.Key
```

The `getData()` method returns an `Object` (but in this case the `Object` returned has the `HashMap` structure).  `MyClass.Key` is an enum that I have created for the purposes of my application (in another class file - `MyClass`).

When I created a foreach loop with the same structure in `MyClass.java`, I did not encounter this problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There no need to cast getData() to a HashMap when you're just going to assign it to a Map. Rather cast it a Map. What if getData() returns a non-HashMap (like a TreeMap)?

Comment: I actually left out some information here...getData() is actually getData(String key), where key specifies the desired Object I wish to get. So since I know the Object I am getting, I know exactly what I should cast it to.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A slightly more efficient way to do this:

```
  Map<MyClass.Key, String> data = (HashMap<MyClass.Key, String>) getData(); 
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  for (Map.Entry<MyClass.Key,String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
       sb.append(entry.getKey());
       sb.append(": ");
       sb.append(entry.getValue());
   }
   return sb.toString();
```

If at all possible, define "getData" so you don't need the cast.

Comment: Upvoted this since .entrySet() is the most efficient way of iterating through Map and it holds original references to the Map so if you alter the Entry you alter the actual map and so on. It's also very convenient.

Comment: I would, but getData() is used all over this project as well as others, so it's best to leave it as is (returning an Object).

Comment: +1, you should definitely change getData() to return Map<MyClass.Key, String>.  It will not break older code.

Comment: awesome example! thanks. i needed to use entry.getKey() and entry.getValue().

Comment: @ufk - you're right.  That's what I get for writing code off the top of my head instead of looking at the API docs.  When you've used as many languages as I have, you can't always keep every detail of the API in memory.

Answer (score 38):

Change:

```
Map data = (HashMap<MyClass.Key, String>) getData();
```

to

```
Map<MyClass.Key, String> data = (HashMap<MyClass.Key, String>) getData();
```

The problem is that `data.keySet()` returns a `Collection<Object>` if data is just a `Map`.  Once you make it generic, `keySet()` will return a `Collection<MyClass.Key>`.  Even better... iterate over the `entrySet()`, which will be a `Collection<MyClass.Key, String>`.  It avoids the extra hash lookups.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why that fixes it?

Comment: Because the way you declared it, Map data, declares data as a Map of unknown type, so keySet() returns Object.  Making the change tells the compiler that the keys are MyClass.Key, not Object.

Comment: When you assign getData to just Map data you're actually assigning it to Map<Object, Object> by explicitly defining it as Map<MyClass.Key, String> data you allow the foreach loop to retain knowledge of what type the key is.

Comment: @cletus, true, but that was not a problem in this question.

Comment: I don't think cletus read my answer.  Obviously you could/should use both.

Answer (score 5):

You could grab the entrySet instead, to avoid needing the key class:

```
private String dataToString(){    
    Map data = (HashMap<MyClass.Key, String>) getData();    
    String toString = "";    
    for( Map.Entry entry: data.entrySet() ) {        
        toString += entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue();
    }    
    return toString;
}
```

Comment: Iterating through the entrySet is more efficient than going through the keySet, even though I need to output the names of the keys as well?

Comment: The entrySet is more efficient because you don't have to do a lookup on every key.

Comment: @Blue - way more efficient BECAUSE you're using both key and value.

Answer (score 5):

I found this simple example at [java forum](http://www.engineeringserver.com/forum/foreach_loop_arraylist_primitive_data_hashmap-t2373.0.html). Its **syntax is very similar to the List's foreach**, which was what I was looking for.

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
HashMap nameAndAges = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : nameAndAges.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Name : " + entry.getKey() + " age " + entry.getValue());
}
```

[EDIT:] I tested it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Motlin's answer is correct.

I have two notes...

1. Don't use `toString += ...`, but use `StringBuilder` instead and append data to it.
2. Cast which Martin suggested will give you unchecked warning, which you won't be able to get rid of, because it is really unsafe.

Another way, without warning (and with StringBuilder):

```
private String dataToString(){
    Map<?, ?> data = (Map<?, ?>) getData();
    StringBuilder toString = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object key: data.keySet()) {
        toString.append(key.toString());
        toString.append(": ");
        toString.append(data.get(key));
    }
    return toString.toString();
}
```

This works, because toString method which you call on `key` is defined in Object class, so you don't need casting at all.

Using `entrySet` is even better way, as it doesn't need to do another look-up in map.

Comment: You can get rid of the warning with @SuppressWarning("unchecked")

Comment: That's just hiding problems, not really fixing them. @SuppressWarning("unchecked") should be used with GREAT caution.

Comment: I am wondering if it is better to store data.keSet() in a local variable or is the foreach loop optimized?

Comment: @Alfred: you don't need to store data.keySet() into your own variable. for (Object key: data.keySet()) is funcionally equivalent to:
Iterator<Object> i = data.keySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Object key = i.next();
    ... rest of for loop goes here ...
}

That is, data.keySet() is evaluated only once.