# Separated string created in loop

Tags: c#, .net, sql, loops

I'm searching the best way to create a string separated with another in a loop. I mean, for example, SQL reader:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(reader.Read())
{
  sb.Append(reader[0]);
  sb.Append("<br />");
}
string result = sb.ToString();
result = result.Remove(result.LastIndexOf("<br />")); // <-
```

or creating SQL query string;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string v in values)
{
  sb.Append(v);
  sb.Append(",");
}
string query = sb.ToString()
query = query.Remove(query.LastIndexOf(",")); // <-
query = String.Concat("INSERT INTO [foo] ([bar]) VALUES(", query, ")");
```

This is the best I have found:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>;
while(reader.Read())
{
  list.Add(reader[0]);
}
string result = String.Join("<br />", list.ToArray());
```

**Edit:** <strike>I know about `StringBuilder`, I didn't used it here just for some clarity</strike>. My general idea do not use `Remove` / `LastIndexOf` !

Comment: He is looking for the best way to create a string by itterativly adding string components together.

Comment: Ok, now your question has been edited, so the answers don't make much sense. :) But still it hurts my eye to see using StringBuilder and String.Concat in the same line.. That doesn't make much sense either. :)

Comment: Thanks for tip! I have edited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not a fan of StringBuilder unless you really know that you need to worry about performance.  It produces ugly code.  I would write it this way...

```
private IEnumerable<string> ReadAllStrings(DataReader reader)
{
    while(reader.Read())
        yield return reader[0];
}


String.Join("<br />", ReadAllStrings(reader).ToArray());
```

If I were doing it a lot, I might consider an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string JoinWith(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string separator)
    {
        return String.Join(separator, strings.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then, my code would look like this:

```
ReadAllStrings(reader).JoinWith("<br />");
```

Comment: I agree, Join internally copies all strings to the same buffer, without new allocations.

Comment: So you're using the same String.Join(String, IEnumerable<string>.ToArray()) too -- I think it's the best way, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best way.  But in your example, you are creating TWO copies of the collection.  One for List and one for ToArray().  In mine, you only create one array.

Comment: I prefer the extention method way. Added a couple of very similar extention methods to the code where I work. Makes things so much easier and readable...

Comment: Hmm.. I thought ToArray() just creates an array, which is passed to String.Join immediately. Do uou mean this array to be the second copy, yea? I don't know yet how to use 'yield' statement. I have to learn it, I'll do.

Comment: Yes, learn about the yield statement.  It will change your world.  You will find that only one collection is created when I call ToArray().  The ReadAllStrings() method does not create a collection, it creates an IEnumerable<>, which is VERY, VERY different.

Comment: It has to at least do an extra iteration to process the .ToArray() instruction.  I don't know it ever creates an extra copy in memory, though, and the clarity of the code probably pays for it.

Comment: The one other thing I would do is add the column index as a parameter for ReadAllStrings, rather than hard code it into the method.

Comment: I don't create even one collection/array in my Join(IEnumerable) (see below).
@Joel yes it does.

Answer (score 5):

How's about:

```
StringBuilder builder;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if( builder == null )
    {
        builder = new StringBuilder(reader[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Append("<br />");
        builder.Append(reader[0]);
    }
}
string result = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Looks nice! I think it's the best 'classic' solution, I mean for .NET 2.0, without using extensions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a combination of several of the better ideas shown:

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static string JoinStrings(this DataReader reader, int ColumnIndex, string delimiter)
    {
        var result = new StringBuidler();
        var delim = String.Empty;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           result.Append(delim).Append(reader[ColumnIndex].ToString());
           delim = delimiter;
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is call it like this:

```
string result = reader.JoinStrings(0, "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another .Net 2.0 solution - change the order:

```
reader.Read();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(reader[0]);
while(reader.Read())
{
  sb.Append("<br />");
  sb.Append(reader[0]);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This will fail if the query returned no rows- but all it really needs is another if statement so it's not that bad.

Comment: indeed it would, but a lot of the solutions here would do the same.  There is also no datatype conversion from what the reader is returning, and there is no point actually assigning the value of the StringReader to result, but it shows the point.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Separator 
{

    private string sep;
    private bool first = true;

    public Separator(string sep) 
    {
        this.sep = sep;
    }

    public virtual string ToString() 
    {
        string reply = first ? "" : sep;
        first = false;
        return reply;
    }
}

var sep = new Separator("<br/>");
var builder = new StringBuilder();
while (reader.Read())
{
    builder.Append (sep.ToString()) ;
    builder.Append (reader[0]) ;
}
```

Comment: You had a bug, but I fixed it.