# Running a method on all objects in a HashMap

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap

I think i misunderstood the application of HashMap when i was rewriting parts of my code to make it more maintainable.

`joints` is a HashMap containing a set of objects identified by a `String`:

`private HashMap<String, SomeObject> joints = new HashMap(5, 1);`

Population of the HashMap is straightforward enough via the `put()` method. However I now need to run a method on each of them. The below code produces a syntax error at the first period, but i believe it illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
joints.("knee").someMethod(someValue);
joints.("hip").someMethod(someOtherValue);
joints.("shoulder").someMethod(someOtherValue);
joints.("neck").someMethod(someOtherValue);
joints.("elbow").someMethod(someOtherValue);
```

What would be a valid/correct equivalent? of the above? I am thinking get() the object, delete it from the map, modify the object, put() it back into the HashMap.

While a foreach would be a step closer, this is a moot approach as the arguements for someMethod() are different for each object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a foreach loop in Java to loop through the values in a HashMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448122/how-do-i-use-a-foreach-loop-in-java-to-loop-through-the-values-in-a-hashmap)

Comment: @DavidPostill not as far as i can see. The second question is related, but the first one is not a duplicate, as this is more of a question about syntax

Comment: Read the manual. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html HINT: The method is named `.get(Object)`

Comment: @Unihedron I concluded that it wasn't the one, as I believed that would modify a copy of the object, rather than the object in the HashMap, but it works contrary to my intuition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a specific value in a `Map` (as opposed to looping over them all), use the `get` method.

```
joints.get("knee").someMethod(someValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice way might be to use a generic method.

First, define an interface with your method that is common to all values in the map:

```
public interface SomeInterface {

    public void someMethod();

}
```

Then, you can iterate over your map and call the common method for each value:

```
public <T extends SomeInterface> void callMethodOnValues(Map<String, T> map) {
    for (T value : map.values()) {
       value.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now elaborate on how we use `someValue` and `someOtherValue` and your answer will be exemplary.

Answer (score 0):

If the `value` retrieved from the `key` is an instance of a class that implements `someMethod()` then it would be like this:

```
for(String key: joints.keySet())
{
   someObject obj = joints.get(key);
   obj.someMethod(value);
}
```